# Eliminar saltos de línea de archivo json

Tags: python, json, datos

soy estudiante de desarrollo de aplicaciones y me gustaría hacer un análisis de ofertas laborales desde la API de InfoJobs, el problema surge cuando recibo la respuesta de la API en formato json hay una sección de las ofertas laborales en la que hay varios saltos de línea y al intentar importarlo a python me da error, os dejo parte del código, por si se os ocurre cual seria la mejor forma de eliminarlas, gracias de antemano.

(Los saltos de linea se producen en requirementMin)

```
author": {
            "id": "**",
            "name": "**",
            "uri": "***",
            "logoUrl": "***",
            "corporateResponsive": false,
            "showCorporativeHeader": false
         },
         "requirementMin": "¿Qué harás en Walters People?
Te encargarás de la toma de requisitos con cliente, búsqueda directa de candidatos, realización de entrevistas presenciales e informes y seguimiento de candidatos durante todo el proceso de selección.
 
Por otro lado, participarás activamente en las acciones de desarrollo de negocio para la captación de nuevos clientes.
 
¿Qué estamos buscando?
Una persona con al menos 1 - 2 años de experiencia en selección de perfiles IT, en consultoría de RRHH o dentro del departamento de desarrollo de negocio.
 
Buscamos una persona proactiva, que le guste el trato con clientes y con buenas dotes de comunicación y negociación.
 
Deberás aportar un nivel de inglés medio - alto.
 
Si estás interesad@ en formar parte de una empresa en crecimiento con un plan de carrera establecido desde el comienzo, donde se valora realmente tu trabajo y tus méritos, y tienes ganas de crecer profesionalmente, inscríbete en nuestra oferta.
!Queremos conocerte!",
         "bold": false,
         "applications": "0",
         "subSegment": 21,
         "executive": false,
         "salaryDescription": "Salario no disponible",
         "urgent": false,
         "color": false
      },
```

Comment: El formato JSON no admite valores multilínea, por lo que ese fichero json estaría mal construido. Para poder procesarlo puedes usar el módulo [multiline](https://pypi.org/project/multiline/) como _wrapper_ del módulo estándar `json`.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que esos saltos de línea vienen realmente dentro de la cadena JSON, o será un problema causado al visualizarlo? Lo que debería venir dentro de la cadena es `\n` en los lugares donde haya saltos de línea.  Si realmente te está enviando líneas incompletas, no sería JSON estándar, pero el comentario de ChemaCortes sería la solución.

Comment: @ChemaCortes muchas gracias, me a servido de mucha ayuda